# How to select unique values from a column using np.unique in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, unique

I have the following dataframe called Trees.

```
FieldSP Common_name     FIA_code   DBH          Height     Year
BP      Bishop Pine     120        11.3435      45.76023   2014
BP      Bishop Pine     120        21.17852     126.86418  2014
CB      CA Bay/Laurel   981        21.19289     114.02973  2011
CB      CA Bay/Laurel   981        24.73787     138.85386  2011
```

The following lines of code are my attempts at getting the unique value for the Year column. There is only one value in this column that is the same for all rows in the dataframe.

```
Year = np.unique(Trees['Year'])

Year = Trees['Year'].iloc[0]

Year = np.unique(Trees[Trees.Year])

if Year == 2014:
    Trees.loc[(Trees['FieldSP'] == 'RW') & (Trees['DBH'] <= 39.37), 'FieldSP'] = 'Rwa'
    Trees.loc[(Trees['FieldSP'] == 'RW') & (Trees['DBH'] <= 39.37), 'FIA_code'] = '211a'
    Trees.loc[(Trees['FieldSP'] == 'RW') & (Trees['DBH'] > 39.37), 'FieldSP'] = 'Rwb'
    Trees.loc[(Trees['FieldSP'] == 'RW') & (Trees['DBH'] > 39.37), 'FIA_code'] = '211b'
elif Year == 2011:
    print('COP 2011 has not been added yet!')
    quit()
else:
    print('the COP year in the treelist is not one we know about. fix it')
quit()
```

This line is being run for multiple dataframes, all with different years (but the year is constant for each dataframe). So I don't want to have to hard code in the value for the year.

I keep getting the following error message when running my script. So it seems that np.unique is creating an empty array. And I don't know how to fix this. Is there a way to select the unique value from the Year column?

```
postfse.py:184: DeprecationWarning: The truth value of an empty array is ambiguous. Returning False, but in future this will result in an error. Use `array.size > 0` to check that an array is not empty.
  if Year == 2014:
postfse.py:189: DeprecationWarning: The truth value of an empty array is ambiguous. Returning False, but in future this will result in an error. Use `array.size > 0` to check that an array is not empty.
  elif Year == 2011:
the year in the treelist is not one we know about. fix it
```

Comment: The lines that your error message is showing is different than the code you've shown. Please provide the section of code which is causing the error.

Comment: And what is the point you are trying to achiever? You already have a column Year. What is the point of getting the year again?

Comment: Thanks Henry for pointing that out. I added the part of the code that is causing the error. Though I think it relates back to how Year is being made.

Comment: Hopefully that also helps answer why I'm trying to get the Year value. For the if statement just added.

Comment: Try: `Year = Trees['Year'].unique()[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Replace
`Year = np.unique(Trees[Trees.Year])`
with `Year = np.unique(Trees['Year'])`

That is if you have to use numpy. I'd just delete the line of code instead, considering I already have Year.

Your question may not be giving the the entire picture of the problem. Are you getting into a situation where a dataframe has no rows?

Comment: So are you saying to do something like the following: 

if Trees['Year'].unique()[0] == 2014:
           XYZ...
        elif Trees['Year'].unique()[0] == 2011:
            ABC...
            quit()

Comment: I'm essentially wanting to run this if statement for multiple dataframes. If the Year value is 2014, then run that part of the statement, if the Year value is 2011 then run the elif statement. But when I try to run the line above Year = np.unique(Trees['Year']), Year is an empty array.